# Exibir variável do Future em um ElevatedButton

Tags: sqlite, variáveis, flutter, dart, async

Estou fazendo a chamada no meu banco de dados do número do embarque, preciso colocar esse número dentro de um botão, porém minha variável "num_embarque" aparece como indefinida dentro do ElevatedButton

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';
import 'Embarque.dart';
import 'Settings.dart';
import 'database/sqlite/connection.dart';

class menu extends StatefulWidget {
  const menu({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _menuState createState() => _menuState();
}

String num_embarque = "";

void main() async {
    Database db = await Connection.get;
    String url = 'SELECT nr_embarque FROM embarque';

    List nr_embarque = await db.rawQuery(url);
          num_embarque = nr_embarque.first["nr_embarque"];

  }


class _menuState extends State<menu> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    
    new Container();
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          brightness: Brightness.dark,
          automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
          title: Text("Embarques"),
          backgroundColor: Color(0xffb0000CD),
        ),
        body: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(32),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.grey[400]),
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              ConstrainedBox(
                constraints: BoxConstraints.tightFor(width: 1000, height: 50),
                child: ElevatedButton(
                  child: Text(
                    "Embarque: $num_embarque",
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 16),
                  ),
                  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                    primary: Color(0xffbDCDCDC),
                    onPrimary: Colors.black,
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) => Embarque(),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 32,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => Settings(),
              ),
            );
          },
          child: const Icon(Icons.settings),
          backgroundColor: Color(0xffb0000CD),
        ));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A variável está como indefinida pois ela não foi definida no escopo que você está tentando utilizá-la. Se você declara uma variável dentro de uma função, ela só irá ficar visível para aquela função:

```
void funcao(){
String variavel = "123";
}
print(variavel); // erro
```

Foi isso que você fez. A variável `String num_embarque` foi definida dentro da função `chamaemb()`. Para contornar esse erro, você deve definir essa variável na sua classe de estado, e de dentro da função apenas alterar seu valor:

```
class _menuState extends State<menu> {
  String num_embarque = ""; //Aqui a declaração da variavel
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
[...]
       num_embarque = nr_embarque.first["nr_embarque"]; // Aqui você muda seu valor
```

Se deseja saber mais sobre esse assunto, você pode pesquisar por [escopo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=escopo) aqui no site que retorna algumas respostas interessantes.

---

Agora que respondida a pergunta propriamente dita, uma observação: Do jeito que você colocou seu código, a função `chamaemb` nunca vai ser chamada. Ela só é declarada dentro do método build. Isso por si só já não deve ser feito. A função build deve ser utilizada apenas para a construção do widget em questão.

Mesmo que, hipoteticamente você passasse a chamar a função `chamaemb`
dentro da sua função, ela seria chamada *toda vez que a tela fosse reconstruída*, o que provavelmente não é sua intenção. Se é uma função assíncrona, provavelmente você não conseguirá ter o resultado entre a chamada da função e o momento em que seu resultado é utilizado.

Existe algumas maneiras de fazer isso, mas uma simples é 1) definir essa função `chamaemb` fora do método build (assim como mostrei com a variável da pergunta). 2) No método initState, chamar essa função. 3)Quando chegar o resultado desejado, lembrar de chamar o `setState()`. Dessa forma a tela irá se redesenhar quando o resultado chegar. Outra forma de conseguir o que deseja é utilizando um [FutureBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html).

Comment: alterei a forma de declarar a variavel como você disse e altero o valor dela posteriormente, porém na hora de exibir está retornando nula, ou seja, a mudança que eu faço ocorre somente dentro do meu método async... Estou fazendo dessa forma:

Comment: editei a pergunta e coloquei o codigo atualizado

Comment: @Igor, as observações que fiz se mantém. Porque você chamou a função de ```main()```? Aonde você está chamando ela? Se você não a chamar, ela nunca vai executar. E se não usar o ```setState()```, ele nunca vai atualizar a tela quando terminar. Leia melhor a segunda parte da minha pergunta, e experimenta [esse](https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await) codelab oficial da Google se quiser um exemplo mais prático. Se tiver alguma dúvida, *pontual e objetiva*, pode editar aqui ou fazer outra no site.